# Receiving long SMS on Android problems

Tags: android, sms, encryption

I have some problem with my code. When I'm receiving SMS's longer than 160 characters the message looks somehow encrypted. For example the text:

> By Matt Brian, The Next Web The new iPad's Retina Display was perhaps
>   the most expected feature to be included in Apple's new tablet,
>   especially after it incorporated the high-resolution display.

Gives the result:

Message 1: èsACiiAèeSCÑY¡(QKAÆKqiA.KÑA(QKAÖKoARaCIgAdKiSÑCAHSgaYCsAnCgA¿KeQCagAhQKAZ§giAJqaKGiKIALKCikeKAh§ADKARÑGYkIKIARÑABaaYKgAÖKoAhCEYKiY¡JgaKGSCYYsABMiKe

Message 2: ÖG§ea§eCiKIAhQKAPSOQÄdKg§YkiS§ÑAHSgaY

The code snippet looks like this:

```
public void onReceive( Context context, Intent intent ){

    // Get the SMS map from Intent
    Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();

    if ( extras != null ){

        // Get received SMS array
        Object[] smsExtra = (Object[]) extras.get( "pdus" );

        for ( int i = 0; i < smsExtra.length; i++ ){

            SmsMessage sms = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[])smsExtra[i]);

            String body = sms.getMessageBody().toString();
            String address = sms.getOriginatingAddress();

            try {

                sendMessageToServer(new Message(address, body));

            } catch (IOException e) {

                Log.w("Receive SMS", "Application not connected to server");
            }                
        }
    }
```

At last I'll add that SMS's containing less than 160 characters are correctly displayed.

Comment: are you using a phone or an emulator? in running the app.